# Remove previous chapter's title from current chapter's header

Tags: header-footer, chapters, report

Title of previous chapter appears in the header of the bibliography chapter in my report.
How can I fix that? I should have " Biblographie" instead of " Liste des publications".[image]

Comment: can  you please add a minimal example of your code?

Comment: Do you have something like `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}` or a `\chapter{Bibliographie}` before the `\printbibliography` ?

Comment: Try `\markboth{Bibliographie}{Bibliographie}` before calling the bibliography.

Comment: this happens with some document classes when `\chapter*` is used (a misfeature, in my opinion).  so it's important to know which document class you are using.  however, the `\markboth` technique mentioned in another comment usually does the job.  but make sure to have a `\newpage` or `\clearpage` command before specifying `\markboth` -- that takes effect immediately.

Comment: @JérômeDequeker: `\addcontentsline` does not set the headers, `\chapter` on the other side may be the villain ;-)

Comment: Thanks all for reacting. It worked when I added
`\clearpage and \markboth{Bibliographie}{Bibliographie}` right before calling bibliorgraphy. Thansk again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I added \clearpage and \markboth{Bibliographie}{Bibliographie} right before calling bibliorgraphy.